Issues in my script to analyze a list of stock ticker symbols
The purpose of this script is to gather basic information about all S&P listed stocks from Wikipedia. It then uses the get symbol to extract price data over time, calculates log.return over that same period, and aggregates the log returns along with the mean, standard deviation, and number of log returns used. The filtered list of traded equities from Wikipedia is then updated with these computations, and they are added to a new table named output.
I can execute this script independently on stock ticker symbols, and it functions without any problems. But the table either gives me an error or doesn't add any data to the output table when I try to use the for loop or analyse stocks functions.
{          
         library(quantmod)   
         library(xts)        
         library(rvest)      
         library(tidyverse)  
         library(stringr)    
         library(forcats)    
         library(lubridate) 

         #Extracting from Wikipedia a S&P Data
         sp_500 <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies") %>%
         html_node("table.wikitable") %>%
         html_table() %>%
         select(`Symbol`, Security, `GICS Sector`, `GICS Sub-Industry`) %>%
         as_tibble()

         #Creating an empty tibble table
         tbl_colnames <- c("ticker.symbol","security","gics.sector",
                  "gics.sub.industry", "mean_return", "sd_return", "days")
         output <- tibble::tibble(!!!tbl_colnames, .rows = 0, .name_repair = ~ tbl_colnames)

         #Sample list of Stock symbols
         symbol_list = c("TSLA", "AKAM","ACN")

         #Function to analyze stocks symbols
         analyze_stocks = function(stocks){
         for (i in stocks){ 
         stock_prices_xts <- getSymbols(i, auto.assign = FALSE)
         names(stock_prices_xts) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close", "Volume", "Adjusted")
         stock_prices <- stock_prices_xts %>%
               as_tibble() %>%
               rownames_to_column(var = "Date") %>%
               mutate(Date = index(stock_prices_xts))

        if (!is.xts(stock_prices)) {
        x <- xts(stock_prices[,-1], order.by = stock_prices$Date)
        }
        log_returns_xts <- periodReturn(x$Adjusted, type = 'log', period = 'daily')
        names(log_returns_xts) <- "Log.Returns"
        log_returns <- log_returns_xts %>%
                    as_tibble() %>%
                    rownames_to_column(var = "Date") %>%
                    mutate(Date = index(log_returns_xts))
  
        stock_prices_xts = merge.xts(stock_prices_xts, log_returns_xts)
  
        output = rbind(output, sp_500 %>% as_tibble() %>%
                   filter(sp_500$Symbol == stocks(i)) %>% 
                   mutate(mean_return = mean(log_returns_xts), sd_return = sd(log_returns_xts), days = nrow(log_returns_xts)))
         }
         return(output)
       }
       analyze_stocks(symbol_list)

}

Sometimes I get these errors when I try to use the for loop or the Analyze stock function.
{
       Error in `filter()`:
       ℹ In argument: `sp_500$Symbol == stocks(i)`.
       Caused by error in `stocks()`:
      ! could not find function "stocks"
}


Not a solution, but some observations.  1.  You may be a victim of lazy evaluation.  Switch to using lapply and see if that helps.  2.  rbinding inside a loop is very inefficient.  After switching to lapply, use rbindlist (or bind_rows) on the list returned.  3. Your loop is for (i in stocks), so filter(sp_500$Symbol == stocks(i)) should probably be filter(Symbol == i).  That is also the cause of your "Unable to find function stocks" error.

To convert xts object AAPL to a data frame use DF <- AAPL %>% fortify.zoo(name = "Date") %>% rename_with(~ sub(".*\\.", "", .x))
